# Tesseract OCR incorrect result

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I have images like this [image: Orig OCR image]
When trying to use C# TesseractOCR to read them, I sometimes get result 38845283-05 which is incorrect because the '3' at the beginning is something that should not be there.
This is page.ThresholdedImage image directly from Tesseract result:
[image: thresholded image]
Even if I pass this image to Tesseract I get the same wrong 38845283-05 result.

Or in this: [image: date image] I get 13.11.238  even though I have ROI region set quite near the characters.

Seems like 3 or 8 are being recognized twice.

I have tried different EngineModes, different PageSegModes but I have not found reliable settings yet.

Do you have some advice?  ( Except training :) )
Thank you.

Even on tesseract.projectnaptha.com the result is wrong:
[image]

Comment: Does it happen only with the "border" ones? (Beginning or End) Never in the middle? What are the confidence levels?

Comment: ^^ Asking because I've been OCRing (not with Tesseract, though) _waaaaayyyy_ worse images and I am really surprised you are _not_ getting near-100% results. They look fabulous.

Comment: Seems like only the border ones are the problem. I'm surprised too. I have tried gazilions ways but I'm not able to pass 99.7% accuracy on 8100 images. Every method I try introduces different errors and fails to read different images...

Comment: Training of Tesseract :) since I'm planning to use it in many simmilar scenarious and retraining every time is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

tesseract has no problem with your images:

```
tesseract WOsO1.png -
8845283-05

tesseract hTTcW.png -
13.11.23
```

IMO you should check your code, make sure you use the latest version, correct language data etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problems were caused by the resolution of the images and the DPI settings of the images.

I have come across this Willus study of resolution impact on accuracy:
https://www.willus.com/blog.shtml?tesseract_accuracy
https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/Wdh_JJwnw94/m/24JHDYQbBQAJ
Thank you Willus.

Based on that I have made my own study where I have found I have to scale the image to somewhere between 0.1-0.2 size of the original image (the height of numbers between 13px-24px) to get most reliable results and set it's DPI to 300.

But still not as stable as I would expect on such OCR task.